# Joining Two Child Tables of a Single Parent, to retrieve the data - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two child tables naming `imported_cables_entry` and `imported_cables_entry`, and a parent table called `cables_entry`. The two children have foreign keys columns called  `cables_id` pointing the primary key `id` of `cables_entry`.

What I want to achieve is, to write a query, which retrieves all the data from parent matching the following conditions :

if `imported_cables_entry`.`cables_id` = `cables_entry`.`id`
if `local_cables_entry`.`cables_id` = `cables_entry`.`id`

Both of these conditions works fine, but retrieves  0 results. When they are executed one by one, then I get the proper results.

> Retrieve all the data from parent table, where the conditions for child tables meets. When the Unique `id` of the parent and the `cables_id` of the children matches with either conditions.

**Query**

```js
SELECT `cables_entry`.*, `imported_cables_entry`.*, `local_cables_entry`.* 
 FROM `cables_entry`
JOIN `imported_cables_entry` 
 ON `imported_cables_entry`.`cables_id` = `cables_entry`.`id` 
JOIN `local_cables_entry` 
 ON `local_cables_entry`.`cables_id` = `cables_entry`.`id`
```

Comment: Could you please give a sample of data as well as your expected result ? Do you want to display childs columns ? What is the structure of childs tables ?

Comment: @Gosfly yes, I want to display the data from parent and child both, if the `id` of parent meets the `cables_id` of any of the two childrens, that data should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming columns of childs tables are identical, you could write the following query :

```
SELECT 
     ce.*, 
     COALESCE(ice.column1, lce.column1) AS column1, 
     COALESCE(ice.column2, lce.column2) AS column2
FROM cables_entry ce
LEFT JOIN imported_cables_entry ice ON ice.cables_id = ce.id
LEFT JOIN local_cables_entry lce ON lce.cables_id = ce.id
```

If it is possible to have an entry in cables_entry which is not in ice nor lce and if you don't want to display them, you could add a WHERE clause :

```
WHERE ice.id IS NOT NULL OR lce.id IS NOT NULL
```

Edit : if your child tables are completely differents and if you don't bother having multiple null column values, you could simply use the following query :

```
SELECT 
     ce.*, 
     ice.*, 
     lce.*
FROM cables_entry ce
LEFT JOIN imported_cables_entry ice ON ice.cables_id = ce.id
LEFT JOIN local_cables_entry lce ON lce.cables_id = ce.id
```

Comment: What's column1 and column 2 ?

Comment: Columns of your child tables, if you want a more detailed answer, please add the structure of your tables and an expected result.